# UIImageView data persists despite removing image

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, uiimageview, instruments

I have an app that displays two full-screen images, one at a time, in a single `UIImageView`. When the user taps the first image, it fades out and the next one displays. After the second image is displayed, it is cleared and no new image is shown—and hopefully nothing remains in memory.

However, analyzing the app in Instruments, I see that each image takes about 12 MB of memory, but it cumulates. 12 MB when the first image shows, 24 MB when the second image shows, and then the 24 MB remains after the image is cleared. I've been wrestling with this for some time, and can't see where this data is being retained.

A fresh set of eyes on this code would be terrific. This is the method that's called every time the user taps the image:

```
-(void)displayImages{

    [self.slideshowImage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];        
    int imageNumber=(int)self.slideshowImage.tag;

    // Fade in first image
    if (imageNumber==0){
        self.slideshowImage.alpha=0;
        [self.slideshowImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[slideshowImages objectAtIndex:imageNumber]]];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^(void){
                             self.slideshowImage.alpha=1;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             self.slideshowImage.tag=imageNumber+1;
                         }];

    // Fade out current image, fade in next image
    }else if (imageNumber<[slideshowImages count]){
        UIImageView *newImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.slideshowImage.frame];
        [newImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[slideshowImages objectAtIndex:imageNumber]]];
        newImage.alpha=0;
        [self.view addSubview:newImage];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^(void){
                             self.slideshowImage.alpha=0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                              animations:^(void){
                                                  newImage.alpha=1;
                                              }
                                              completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                  [self.slideshowImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[slideshowImages objectAtIndex:imageNumber]]];

                                                  self.slideshowImage.alpha=1;
                                                  [newImage removeFromSuperview];
                                              }];
                         }];
        self.slideshowImage.tag=imageNumber+1;

    // Clear image
    }else{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^(void){
                             self.slideshowImage.alpha=0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self.slideshowImage setTag:0];
                             [self.slideshowImage setImage:nil];
                             [self.slideshowImage setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                         }];
    }

}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you tried setting your `UIImageView` instances to `nil` after you `removeFromSuperview`? I think you probably have a `strong` reference, which won't release the memory as long as the owner is alive.

Comment: Hi @mbm29414, thanks for the comment. I did actually, but no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the implementation of [`-[UIImage imageNamed:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) that is keeping a cache of all images it has loaded.

In the documentation there is a paragraph that describes exactly what is happening in your code:

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using [`imageWithContentsOfFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithContentsOfFile:). This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

But if you want to have good performance, it is almost always better to use the system cache. Loading a 12MB image can take more than 16ms and will delay the UI.

Comment: Hi @Mats, thanks for this—that makes complete sense. Out of interest, would there have been a way in Instruments for me to connect the "imageIO_PNG_Data" row I was getting down to that `imageNamed:` line of code?